# Delphi 7: get money format in string

Tags: delphi

How can in delphi convert :

'1' to '1,00'

or

'1,5'  to '1,50'

e.g All variables are in string.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Format or FormatFloat function. Format example (assuming ',' is decimal separator) is

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ShowMessage(Format('%.2f', [StrToFloat('1,5')]));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the formatFloat function i believe.

```
var
  sText : string;
begin
  sText := '1234';
  showMessage(formatFloat('#,###.00', strToFloat(sText)));
```

-Don.

Answer (score -1):

Use FormatFloat. And it's Delphi, with "i", btw...

Comment: Didn't you see that `FormatFloat` already was mentioned in an answer (with example code)?